# Export Google map directions to lat/long

Tags: google-maps

I have multiple sets of lat/long coordinates that I am using in the Google directions API with way points to get directions following roads and paths. Each set of coordinates have about 100 points which I am converting to a usable number for the start, end and waypoints.

I would like to get the lat/long values from the directions which are returned from Google. Basically get each coordinate from each road segment.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using the [direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponses), you would get a respond like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "geocoded_waypoints" : [
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJ7cv00DwsDogRAMDACa2m4K8",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJ69Pk6jdlyIcRDqM1KDY3Fpg",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJgdL4flSKrYcRnTpP0XQSojM",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     }
  ],
  "routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },
      ...
      ... additional steps of this leg
    ...
    ... additional legs of this route
      "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
      "start_location": {
        "lat": 35.4675602,
        "lng": -97.5164276
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lat": 34.0522342,
        "lng": -118.2436849
      },
      "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
      "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
    } ],
    "copyrights": "Map data ©2010 Google, Sanborn",
    "overview_polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOnzh@vlbBtc~@tsE`vnApw{A`dw@~w\\|tNtqf@l{Yd_Fblh@rxo@b}@xxSfytAblk@xxaBeJxlcBb~t@zbh@jc|Bx}C`rv@rw|@rlhA~dVzeo@vrSnc}Axf]fjz@xfFbw~@dz{A~d{A|zOxbrBbdUvpo@`cFp~xBc`Hk@nurDznmFfwMbwz@bbl@lq~@loPpxq@bw_@v|{CbtY~jGqeMb{iF|n\\~mbDzeVh_Wr|Efc\\x`Ij{kE}mAb~uF{cNd}xBjp]fulBiwJpgg@|kHntyArpb@bijCk_Kv~eGyqTj_|@`uV`k|DcsNdwxAott@r}q@_gc@nu`CnvHx`k@dse@j|p@zpiAp|gEicy@`omFvaErfo@igQxnlApqGze~AsyRzrjAb__@ftyB}pIlo_BflmA~yQftNboWzoAlzp@mz`@|}_@fda@jakEitAn{fB_a]lexClshBtmqAdmY_hLxiZd~XtaBndgC"
    },
    "warnings": [ ],
    "waypoint_order": [ 0, 1 ],
    "bounds": {
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 34.0523600,
        "lng": -118.2435600
      },
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 41.8781100,
        "lng": -87.6297900
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Where you can get the lat/lng of each turning points under steps. You can even decode the polyline to get the set of points which describe the road.